# sql double inner join: using group_concat gives empty result set

Tags: mysql, yii

i have a table `education` containing a person id and an education level id, both foreign keys. i want to group the results so each person record is singular, containing a list of all education levels, so it returns **Jane Doe: master, master**

```
select 
  concat(person.name_first," ",person.name_last) as name,
  group_concat(person_studylevel.description)
from `person_education`
left join person_studylevel on level = person_studylevel.id
left join person on junior = person.id
```

this worked until i added the group_concat(), it then returns an empty result set

ive tried using the result as a subquery but that didnt work as well

table structure:

```
person_education: id(int10), junior(int10), level(int10)
person_studylevel: id(int10), description(varchar100)
person: id(int10), name_first(varchar255), name_last(varchar255)
```

Comment: what is your table structure post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out please, if you want to group by each person, then take that table as the first to the left:

- ### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e0e5/3)

Query:

```
select 
  concat(p.name_first," ",p.name_last) as name,
  group_concat(ps.description)
from person p 
left join person_education pe
on p.id = pe.junior
left join person_studylevel ps
on pe.level = ps.id
group by p.id
;

| NAME | GROUP_CONCAT(PS.DESCRIPTION) |
---------------------------------------
|  j k |               degree,masters |
|  a g |               diploma,degree |
|  b h |                         cert |
|  c i |                       (null) |
|  d m |                       (null) |
```

Comment: @aelgoa please give this query a try and comment :) would like to hear if you need further help or if the sample schema I created needs changes.

Comment: +1 for your question. And if you need to filter out those who have no educations levels, then you can use `and not ps.description is null` =)

Comment: thank you. you came up with the same solution i did, but i forgot to add a **group by** clause.

Comment: :D when *grouping* you need to `group by`

Comment: yes, its so obvious it barely get's a mention in examples.
also, swapping the joins doesnt affect the result.

Comment: Since you,are using left join swapping might not affect, but if you had used inner join you will not get all users. So its best to keep the table that you need everything in the left join and rest can be inner join if you need. :-)